# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with inserting data into database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I created a connection with a Microsoft sql database and am trying to add basic informastion as part of an exercise but get the following error.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

This is how I connect to the database

```
SqlConnection sqlConn; 
protected void butConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=lrmg;Integrated Security=True;";
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        labMessage.Text = "a connection to your database was established";
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlE)
    {
        labMessage.Text = sqlE.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        labMessage.Text = exe.Message;
    }
```

Here is where I get the error

```
 protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   try
    {
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string date = txtDate.Text;

        **SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();**

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Canditate(Name, Doj) VALUES('" + name + "'," + date + ")";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        labMessage.Text = "The value was inserted into your database";
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlE)
    {
        labMessage.Text = sqlE.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        labMessage.Text = exe.Message;
    }
}
```

I am under the impression that the sql connection was opened so why the exception?

Comment: what have you tried? Object reference not set to an instance of an object means something is `NULL` use a debugger!

Comment: +1. Yes. If that is an excersice, then LEARN PROGRAMMING - and using a debugger to find that out is critical. Break on exception, see what variable ls null. Use your brain (yes, you have one) to find out why. And use parameters for your SQL.

Comment: Check your connection string, create the sqlconnection object and step through to see if it's initialized correctly.

Comment: And you should not use SQL commands like this, because of SQL-Injections. Use parameterized commands instead.

Comment: remove the try catch to find out what line exactly you have the exception.

Comment: maybe some behavior deescription should help. Are you pressing the connect button before the submit? What does the labMessage shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a dedicated method to open the connection, that you'd invoke every time you're using the connection. With your current setup, butConnect_click MUST be called before butSumbit_Click in the same request. So add the call to butConnect in butSubmit.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because reference variable `sqlConn` is null - that is happening probably because

- From you code snippet, connection is getting created and opened in
  connect button click. So you need to hit connect before submit
- Most likely cause is probably different assuming that this ASP.NET code - in such case, every request is served by different instance of page class - so if you open connection on one request (connect click), it (that variable) won't be available in next request (submit click). The remedy is simple - create and open connection when you need it i.e. in submit click. On the other hand, you probably need to understand mode about web programming models to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You use two different events to do your work on the database. Why? Have you ever heard of connection pooling?
Probably between the first event (open connection) and second event (db insert) something happens and change your global variable SqlConn to null and you get the error. (Of course I am assuming that you press that button to open the connection before trying to insert anything)

With [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) this kind of programming pattern is no more necessary, instead, when you need to update/insert/delete/select something you open the connection, do your work and close immediately the connection without keeping it open and consuming resources on the server and client side.

```
try
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
                              "Initial Catalog=lrmg;Integrated Security=True;";
    using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();**
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Canditate(Name, Doj) VALUES(@name, @dt)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        labMessage.Text = "The value was inserted into your database";
    }
}
catch (SqlException sqlE)
{
    labMessage.Text = sqlE.Message;

}
catch (Exception exe)
{
    labMessage.Text = exe.Message;
}
```

Notice also that your code is subject to [Sql Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) attacks because you use string concatenation to build your sql text. This is a bad practice that should be avoided at all costs